# Count the number of occurrences of A-Z in column inside a huge file >32GB and avoid 26 if conditions

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to get the count of A-Z and a-z from 18th column of a very huge file.

Here is my current solution. This solution works but would take hours as this would require 52 loops over the huge file. To avoid multiple loop , I could create 52 checks for each of A-Z and a-z. But is there a better way to avoid so many if conditions?

```
for y in {A..Z} {a..z}
do
  Vars2[$y]=$(awk -v val="$y" '( $1 == "f" && $18 ~ val)  { print $18 }' $FILE | wc -l)
done
```

Every line in the file has one of A-Z or a-z.

Sample log line:

```
f - - - - - - - - - - - - 200 application/json - TLSv1.3 gW 0 - - 6676f3f1
```

```
Sample output:
A - 0
B - 0
C - 0
D - 469
E - 0
F - 0
G - 2976
H - 0
I - 0
J - 0
K - 0
L - 13
M - 0
N - 0
O - 0
P - 4516
Q - 0
R - 560
S - 0
T - 0
U - 0
V - 0
W - 1
X - 0
Y - 0
Z - 0
a - 819
b - 3
c - 0
d - 18
e - 0
f - 13
g - 1289
h - 0
i - 0
j - 0
k - 263
l - 9
m - 0
n - 0
o - 6740
p - 573
q - 0
r - 0
s - 0
t - 0
u - 0
v - 0
w - 0
x - 658
y - 1
z - 0
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I would look into doing it in a "real" language since bash can be slow.  A basic C program would work much faster (as do other languages).

Comment: (1) By 18th column you mean 18th character of each line, or 18th word? (2) Is 18th column always 1 character? (3) If 18th column is "aabbb", should you increment "a" counter by 2 and "b" counter by 3?  or you increment "a" counter and "b" counter by 1?

Comment: its the 18th word separated by space. This is evident from my awk command

Comment: The 18th word in your example is "gW" -- is that supposed to count as one "g" and separately one "W"?

Comment: yes, this should be counted as 1 g and 1 W.

Comment: @user31264 , The characters will be always unique in a single line. For example "abcd". This will never be "aabbcc". Each of these character count should be incremented by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` GNU awk function to get the characters of the field you want into an array and then loop and count them globally. At the end, you print the total count per character.

```
> cat test.awk
($1=="f") {
    split($18, c, "")
    for (i=1; i <= length(c); i++) {
        count[c[i]]++
    }
}
END {
    split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwz", letters, "")
    for (i=1; i <= length(letters); i++) {
        print letters[i] " - " count[letters[i]]+0
    }
}
```

output

```
> awk -f test.awk file
A - 0
B - 0
C - 0
D - 0
E - 0
F - 0
G - 0
H - 0
I - 0
J - 0
K - 0
L - 0
M - 0
N - 0
O - 0
P - 0
Q - 0
R - 0
S - 0
T - 0
U - 0
V - 0
W - 1
Z - 0
a - 0
b - 0
c - 0
d - 0
e - 0
f - 0
g - 1
h - 0
i - 0
j - 0
k - 0
l - 0
m - 0
n - 0
o - 0
p - 0
q - 0
r - 0
s - 0
t - 0
u - 0
v - 0
w - 0
z - 0
```

some notes:

- `for` loop with a counter preserves the order of the letters.
- Letters hardcoded are used to display the requested output, where all letters exist, included them with zero count.
- `+0` ensures that we print zero instead of nothing.

Answer (score 2):

How about accumulating counts in an `awk` array in a single pass:

```
awk '( $1 == "f" ) { count[$18]++ }; END { for (key in count) { print key " - " count[key] }}' "$FILE"
```

Edit: If the field can have multiple characters and you want to count each separately, you need to loop over them and add each to `count` separately:

```
awk '( $1 == "f" ) {
         split($18, chars, "");
         for (i in chars) { count[chars[i]]++ }
     };
     END {
         for (char in count) { print char " - " count[char] }
     }' "$FILE"
```

Comment: This would work if 18th word is only a character , but this could be combination of A-Z or a-z. For example an 18th field looks like "paRbx".

Comment: Great answer and a simpler one too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the speed with a file of your size, but how about

```
grep ^f "$FILE" | cut -d ' ' -f 18 | grep -o '[[:upper:][:lower:]]'| sort | uniq -c
```

? The `-o` outputs each character in a separate line and the `-c` takes care about counting.

**UPDATE** : Added the restriction to the 18th field. Also filtered by letter 'f' in the first position, because the code in the question is doing this too.

Comment: Did you mean first awk the 18th field ?
awk '( $1=="f" ){print $18 }' test.log | grep -o '[[:upper:][:lower:]]' | sort | uniq -c

Comment: This is equally good and it works too. But I am not sure of the time complexity.

Comment: @kelvin : Ah, right. Forgot about extracting the column. Will update my anser.

Comment: @kelvin : Just in case you try out several of the solutions proposed here .... Maybe you could then post also a time comparision? It would be interesting.

Comment: Made the comparison. Here is the time difference. 
1. using awk 601 secs
2. using grep 608 secs

Comment: Thank you. This surprises me; I had expected a larger difference, in one direction or the other.

Answer (score 0):

First do `awk '$1 == "f" {print($18)}' myfile > col18.txt`.  Then count characters a-zA-Z in the file `col18.txt` which will probably be much smaller than 32Gb.

Comment: All the lines have the characters in the 18th field. So I am afraid this solution will not work.

Comment: @kelvin Pipe the output through `| sort | uniq -c` to get per-character counts.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the lines have the characters in the 18th field", and why this solution will not work because of it?

Comment: Since all the line have this filed , if we pipe the output , this new file will effectively have the same size as the original one.